# More information about updating an ActiveRecord avoiding 'attr_accessible'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to know some behaviours of this code:

```
@user.send :attributes=, @attrib, false
```

*That is from [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attributes%3D).*

If I have a form that return these parameters to my controller:

```
params[:name]
params[:surname]
params[:email]
```

and in the controller I use

```
@user.send( # Avoiding 'attr_accessible'
  :attributes=, {
  :name => params[:name],
  :surname => params[:surname] },
  false )

@user.save
```

it should save only 'name' and 'surname' attributes for the @user ActiveRecord. I tryed that, and it works as expected. But...

`1.` **is it possible that a malicious user can set the email value in someway on the saving process (also if the email attribute is not considered in the "send" statement)?**

`2.` **is it right the following statement?**

> Calling attributes= with false doesn't
>   update anything yet, it just sets the
>   attribute values while ignoring any
>   attr_accessible whitelist.
>
> So you can just call save afterwards,
>   which returns the boolean value you're
>   looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will definitely not allow a malicious user to set the email. I would recommend using the following code though, since it performs the same thing and is easier to read:

```
@user.name = params[:name]
@user.surname = params[:surname]
@user.save
```

Also, passing true as the second parameter to attributes= allows you to protect your attributes using attr_protected and attr_accessible. You can view the documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attributes%3D). That means your statement is correct: passing false as the second attribute ignores your mass-assignment protected attributes.

Comment: For the point 2, I was referring to this: is '@user.send(...)' enough to update the '@user' object? That is, the use of '@user.save' is necessary or not?

Comment: No, you have to call @user.save as well when simply calling attributes=.